# How to select rows from a table where a word appears? (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have to make a search for keywords as part of my Computer Science work.

I have the names and descriptions of several DVD's.

The user has to search a word, and then displayed are all the names of DVD's where the word appeared in either the title or description.

Let's say my columns in my table
 were "dvd title" and "description", and the word the person has entered is $keyword.

How would i select rows in mysql where $keyword appears at least once in either columns "dvd title" and "description".

Thanks for reading. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a full text index on those columns, but that probably isn't what they want you do do.

You need wildcards, and to you wildcards compare with the keyword LIKE instead of =.  A wildcard in mysql is %

```
SELECT * FROM mutable WHERE dvdtitle like '%keyword%' or description like '%keyword%';
```

As for using PHP variable and creating the string, you've got to do some of your own homework.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i found your answer the best because you explained it best for me. I know how to do the PHP variable and string so that won't be a problem :) just didn't know which clause to use and i hadn't a clue about the wildcards... Thanks again for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table_name 
WHERE   dvd_title like '%$keyword%' 
OR      description like '%$keyword%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code sample, it's not a full code but will give you an idea:

```
$query_str = "select * from dvd_table_name where dvd_title like '%$keyword%' or description like '%$keyword%'";
$qh = mysql_query($query_str);
```

Then use mysql_fetch_assoc($qh) to retrive data using while loop;

Comment: I'm up voting this. most complete answer so far for such a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE dvdtitle LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR description LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";
```

Executing the above SQL query would return all the rows in the table that has the specified keyword in either the column `dvdtitle` or `description`.